# VScode does not count tests that throw exceptions (0/0 tests passed)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

My dev environment is:

```
vscode 1.80.1
python 3.10
using the python extension for vscode v2023.12.0
```

My test file:

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_say_hello(self) -> None:
        raise Exception("test")
```

My vscode settings:

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./runner",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
}
```

I would expect that when I run the test to show an error because of the raised exception, but it does not. Instead, the "testing" tab in vscode shows (0/0 tests passed):

[image]

Worst, if the tests was previously passing it would still show up with a green mark! The "Tests Results" tab simply shows: "Finished running tests!" with no other outputs. If I run the test in debug mode, I correctly get the output error, but the tests is still not marked as incorrect:

[image]

Running unittests manually outside vscode correctly display the error (just like the output in debug mode).

So how do I get vscode to display my failing tests?

Comment: If you mean to file a bug report, please do it in a place where the developers can be expected to see it. If you mean to ask a question, please actually do so.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 If you're old enough to use a keyboard, then you're old enough to know that throwing insults at the people who you want to help you out of the goodness of their hearts is a... Profoundly. Bad. Idea.

Comment: Sorry, who was trying to help here? I only see someone being voluntarily obtuse. In fact, I had to find the solution myself because nobody was actually of any help whatsoever.

Comment: @MyUsername112358 Actually, I'd say that the fact that you found the solution yourself in less than an hour by doing what Karl suggested means that A: Karl was helpful. B: You could have solved it yourself (as demonstrated) and completely skipped posting to S.O. or throwing a temper tantrum.

Comment: I didn't find the solution based on what Karl suggested, don't give him credit for something he absolutely had zero impact on. The only thing Karl did was fail to understand the implicit question in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is a known issue and there is already a fix pushed to the main branch, but it is not present in the live version yet:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/21630